# auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(link.url) returns false for some reason

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Currently, I'm creating an app using react-native expo and Firebase.
So far I succeeded in connecting to my project through android and also succeeded signing up through all the methods I tried signing up with, well except for one, the email link method.

At first, I'm sending an email link using this function:

```js
const actionCodeSettings = {
      url: "https://myapp.page.link/loginemail", //A dynamic link i created in firebase
      handleCodeInApp: true
    };
    auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
  };
```

The link was indeed sent to the email I provided, and when I pressed it from my android phone, it opened it.
Now, here's the catch,
for some reason, when the app opens and I call:
`auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(link.url)` 
it returns false

I then printed the link and it gave me:

```js
{  
    "utmParameters": {},  
    "minimumAppVersion": null,  
    "url": "https://my-app-id.firebaseapp.com"  
}
```

The URL is the same URL I assigned to the dynamic link as a deep link.

Hope one y'all can help me, I will provide more info in case I didn't provide enough.
Thanks in advance!